# Programmer's text editor with vertical split view for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, text-editors, textmate

I have been using TextMate 'til now, but I am missing exactly one feature: vertical split view.

I know that Coda supports it, but I am not a big fan of a huge IDE which changes my workflow too much – in other words, I hate it if one application takes over my job.

TextMate is actually all I need:

- code completion
- syntax highlighting
- snippets
- filebrowser (project folder)
- accessible via the terminal

But the Vertical Split is just one feature I am really looking for. Have you an idea which editor could be the solution to my problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *vertical* split (it's somewhat ambiguous) but TextWrangler (free) and it's payware big brother BBEdit are both very good and let you split the window in one axis, at least.

Comment: @Spectator vertical splits would be extremely nice. I've looked at a few different *IDE's* (PyCharm, Eclipse, KomodoEdit), but have ended up sticking with mvim as my text editor of choice, sacrificing amenities like a Snippets filebrowser or code completion that works the way I like. I like mvim because it keeps my vi and vim chops lean for those times when I find myself using another computer where one of the popular IDE's haven't been installed. Best of luck to you!

Comment: So its almost 9 years past since I have asked this question there are now a lot of options on the market the most acessible ist probably VS Code, atom, I have used vim for a exstensive time. I also used intelij but was really unhappy with it, although the refactoring in intelij is awesome. I switched to spacemacs a couple of month ago and it is by far my favourite option yet. I prefer it over mvim or vim.I also do like vs code a lot although the vim navigation is only almost good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will always answer [Vim](http://www.vim.org) (or [MacVim](http://macvim.org) in this case): it does everything you want, some more and runs on every platform which gets the next hype!

[image: MacVim]

You can split horizontally and vertically until you bleed. If you shy away from the steep learning curve of pure VIM, you can make [Cream](http://cream.sf.net/) to tune Vim into an easier and "more to the standards" version ... but of course you can still vertically split and tab yourself to death.

Comment: +1 for MacVim - it's the best GUI vim on any platform IMO. You also have the benefit that many people who used TextMate have switched to vim, so there are lots of switcher guides (e.g., http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/).

Answer (score 4):

[Emacs runs on OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and is a very popular editor for code, text and well...  just about everything.  It was originally very much a geek's editor, but has since become much more simple and easy to use.  You might give it a shot.

Comment: I'll give it a try but as far as I can remeber i couldn't get my had over the shortcuts ... Maybe this time i'll take some more time!

Comment: Short-cuts are now really just that: short-cuts.  Everything is mouse enabled and menu-enabled now.  The short cuts are generally faster to use because your fingers don't have to move to and from the mouse, but most of them aren't *required* any longer.

Answer (score 4):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com) looks promising (probably until TextMate 2 comes along), though it is only in (early) alpha stage.

Here's a Screenshot of the feature you're requesting in SublimeText 2.

[image: Sublime Text 2 split view]

Comment: I am very optimistic over Sublime Text 2 the alpha is working great for me ... i am loving the Fullscreen mode and Splitscreening is perfect. I am just a little sad about seeing the evaluation dialog during public alpha ... I would pay for the editor if it would be a release but for an alpha I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using [TextMate](http://macromates.com/)'s bookmark feature as a substitute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you think you might consider Vim, it definitely has vertical text splitting. You can split your window into as many windows as you like - top and bottom, left and right, two on the top and one on bottom, etc. The splits can be different files or different parts of the same file.

Vim has a steep learning curve, but I'm a big fan, and after watching me use it, my boss is preparing to switch from Textmate to Vim.

If you want to consider it, I'd highly recommend the Peepcode episode on Vim to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fraise](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33751/fraise) or [Smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/). (Fraise is based on and very similar to Smultron.) They both support split view and are both free or very cheap (Smultron costs $5).

Edit:
Link for Smultron changed to current version.

Comment: Note: Fraise is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/)?

It allows you to drag a window so that it resizes to half of the screen. You can also drag a window to resize to full screen. You can use it with Exposé to work with more than two windows.

This would enable you to continue using TextMate or any other editor of choice.

Cinch currently costs $7.

Answer (score 0):

TextWrangler has a sweet split view. Still kinda two windows but check it out. command+click to highlight the two docs you want to compare, then right (control) click and choose compare. Observe the awesomeness.  I posted this on MacRumors as well.

That and a lot of other great tips here:

http://magp.ie/2010/06/16/textwrangl...ard-shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

Another free option is Jedit, available for Mac, Windows and Linux. It can split horizontally and vertically. Sublime looks better, but it's not free. Macvim is another option, but you have to get used to its different way of doing things.

http://jedit.org/